# react app not picking up .env.development files?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a react app with a .env file and .env.development file.

.env file:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:60695/api
```

.env.development:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://test.myapi.com/api
```

I run my app with `"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server --port 3000"`

On my webpack configuration I have the following debug lines:

```
const env = dotenv.config().parsed;
console.log(env);
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

and when I run my start command, the consoloe spits out:

```
{ REACT_APP_API_URL: 'http://localhost:60695/api' }
development
```

which tells me it's reading the .env file but not the .env.development file as expected.

Any ideas why my .env.development file is not getting picked up?

Comment: Hi! I recommend taking a look at this link (DOTENV documentation). It explains why is actually not a good idea to have several .env files: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the parser is reading the `.env.development` portion correctly. Probably also because dotenv doesn't expect multiple env files. As someone has mentioned, its not recommended.

However, if you must, you can try it this way:

```
dotenv.config({
    path: path.resolve(
      __dirname, 
      `PATH_TO_ENV/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
    )
})
```